# score vs. be scored?

Tags: usage

Can ***scored*** be replaced with ***were scored*** in the sentence?
When intransitive verbs are available, are they preferred over the passive forms of transitive verbs most of the time?

> Those who ***scored*** high in conscientiousness were rated by their
> peers as less effective.

Answer (score 1):

One is active-voice and one is passive-voice. Generally, you can't simply swap a an active voice verb with a passive voice "be" + verb. In this specific scenario, however, ***you can*** replace "scored" with "were scored," ***but doing so changes the meaning.***

Saying "***those who scored***" is active-voice and explains that those whose score it is themselves earned that score, like by taking a test, by taking part in some exercise, or by doing whatever it was they did to earn themselves that score, like if this were about a test in school, this usage would refer to "students" performing the action "scored" (i.e., students scored: students earned their test score).

Saying "***those who were scored***" is passive-voice and explains that some unnamed subject or subjects performed an evaluation of those whose score it is, like by grading a test those whose score it is took, by evaluating those whose score it is in some exercise, or whatever it was that had to be scored in order to give those whose score it is their score, like if this were about a test in school, this usage would likely refer to the "teachers" performing the action "scored" (i.e., teachers scored: teachers evaluated students' tests and assigned the test score that each student earned).

Therefore, the answer to your question in this specific circumstance is, yes, you can, *but that's only because the definitions of the verb "score" offer that flexibility*, definitions that are *very* different from each other and so fundamentally change what the sentence is conveying, meaning, yes, you can in this situation use either one, but ***that does not mean they're interchangeable, because "score" and "were scored" do not mean the same thing.***

Comment: I think the easier way to explain as you said is to simply say :
those who scored.., means the ones who scored by themselves

**AND**

those who were scored.., actually means there are two separate groups of **A and B**
which A hunted B and scored them or vice versa

Comment: @AtrinNoori - Not necessarily. The subject is unnamed in the passive-voice construction, so there may be only one group as the group that earned the scores may be the same group that evaluated and assigned the scores, like when teachers often have students exchange tests with each other to grade them such that the same group that "scored" by earning points for right answers is the same group that "scored" by evaluating the answers and awarding points for right answers. Self-evaluation is also common. That's why I didn't explain it the way you did. It's not necessarily right and often isn't.

Comment: yes, that's another view of the storytelling... passive voice is tricky sometimes 
but the idea is the same...  "they haven't scored by themselves"

Comment: @Atrin Noori - Actually, the idea isn't the same. If it's the same group, it's the same group. What's more, it's also extremely common for people to self-evaluate, for each person who earns a score to be the same person who evaluates and assigns that score. This is ESPECIALLY true in situations where there's nothing at stake and it's personal, like personality tests, which is what would measure "conscientiousness," the example given by the OP. So it's entirely possible one who scored high in conscientiousness was assigned that score by oneself, especially given what their peers think.

Comment: What you try to imply is so deep into the idea and that is why I said in my first comment: "The easier way to explain...". 
it's just as simple as that. I don't get the idea of people who scored as the same as the people who were scored. consider a football player who scored a goal and a one who was scored...(and the rest of a sentence). It is like a football player was scored the highest point by the judges or the critics

Comment: I take a test measuring "conscientiousness," like in the question. After I finish taking the test, I use a guide that tells me how to add up my score. I score high. So I scored high in conscientiousness on a test that was scored by me. It's that simple. I'm not the one making it complicated. I'm the one who has generously and patiently spent the last 31 minutes trying to explain what's VERY simple to you so you understand I'm not changing my answer like you want me to because the passive voice names no subject, so it would be WRONG to assume who scored is different than who it was scored by.

Comment: First of... I never asked you to change your answer, I was the one who upvoted it. Second, your assumption is not correct.  You don't actually give yourself a high score it's the test measurements that give the score, So I have to say: "I took the test... I did my best... I got a high score( I was scored high by the test measurements). You know grammatically speaking what you say is wrong. But what you said can ***imply*** what I try to say, which makes it correct. Now, do you understand?

Comment: That's what these comments are for: to correspond with the answerer to improve the answer with corrections, additions, etc. Everything else is chat and violates ELL "Terms and Conditions." So it went without saying your criticism was to get me to change my answer as I'd never assume you were breaking the rules. As for your "second," *you know* that's pure sophistry. That's like saying a teacher doesn't score her students when she, in accordance with a standardized scoring system, scores standard, curriculum-provided, multiple-choice tests her students have completed. Thank you for the upvote.

Comment: By the way, I don't know I'm wrong because I'm not wrong. You saying so doesn't make it so. According to University of Toronto's grammar website, the number one reason provided for "When do I use the passive voice?" is when "The actor is unknown." The only way the actor is known is when a "by" prepositional phrase is included that names the actor. If one isn't included, the actor may be anyone. Anyone. Not *anyone except the recipient of the action*. Anyone. No exceptions. And you relentlessly pushing this fantasy that it's impossible for someone to score their own test is, frankly, bizarre.

Comment: Well I suppose you are right . Thats a good reason